# Excel Cell Alignments: Numerical values for e.g. xlLeft, xlRight or xlCenter?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel, alignment

I've been trying to align Excel cell text values. I've tried the more common `xlLeft`, `xlRight` but this doesn't seem to work. The error was `xlLeft` wasn't declared. I am using Visual Studios and creating a aspx page with VB.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
    Dim oExcel As Object
    Dim oBook As Object
    Dim oSheet As Object

    'Start a new workbook in Excel
    oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add

    'Add data to cells of the first worksheet in the new workbook
    oSheet = oBook.Worksheets(1)

    oSheet.Range("A1:E1").Merge()
    oSheet.Range("A1").Value = "Hello"
    oSheet.Range("A2:E2").Merge()
    oSheet.Range("A2").Value = "There "
    oSheet.Range("A1:A4").Font.Bold = True
    oSheet.Range("A1").HorizontalAlignment = -4131
```

Comment: you should post your code if you want some real help. stackoverflow users are not wizards that can look in their crystal ball to understand what's wrong in your particular case

Comment: ahh yes forgot to add the sample code..Sorry bout that. Added it in.

Answer (score 20):

For `VerticalAlignment`:

```
Top:    -4160
Center: -4108
Bottom: -4107
```

And `HorizontalAlignment`:

```
Left:    -4131
Center:  -4108
Right:   -4152
```

Comment: Do you have a reference for these or did you extract the values by testing them in Excel yourself?

Either way, thank you! This helped me make a minor update on some ancient html -> excel exporter that's using JavaScript with ActiveX.

Answer (score 5):

You can use xlLeft:

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

...
oSheet.Range("A1").HorizontalAlignment = Constants.xlLeft
```

Comment: This is the better way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

```
xcl.Range("J:J").EntireColumn.HorizontalAlignment = _
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Constants.xlCenter
```

Comment: Please consider adding more than just code. Code only answers with no explanation are often downvoted. Please see [answer]